# Possible to get Prestashop back office token from external?

Tags: token, prestashop-1.7

Good morning to everyone.
I'm developing a complex project, where the store (made by prestashop) is just a part of it.
For this reason, I have a main folder and inside it there are a store folder, containing all the prestashop files, and various other folders containing other sections of the project.
In one of these sections, I would like to add a button that takes me directly to the prestashop back office page to add a new product, but to do this I need to get the authentication token.
Do you have any solution to obtain this token, in a section (directory) other than that of Prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

Include the PrestaShop config.php, and you can use all of the PrestaShop functions and methods

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../config/config.inc.php';
```

And now you can create the token with by calling the

```
$tokenProducts = Tools::getAdminTokenLite( 
            'AdminProducts'
        );
```

Comment: Got:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Db::getInstance() in C:\xampp\htdocs\novellarredo\store\config\alias.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\novellarredo\store\classes\shop\Shop.php(1336): pSQL('localhost') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\novellarredo\store\classes\shop\Shop.php(337): ShopCore::findShopByHost('localhost') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\novellarredo\store\config\config.inc.php(118): ShopCore::initialize() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\novellarredo\manage\index.php(6): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\novellarredo\store\config\alias.php on line 47